# in_array only returning true if needle is first item

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array called `$fields`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "groupName"
  [1]=>
  string(9) " userName"
  [2]=>
  string(3) " id"
}
```

However when I run this code:

```
if(in_array("groupName", $fields))
            echo "yes - groupName";

if(in_array("id", $fields))
            echo "yes - id";
```

It outputs this:

> yes - groupName

Can't understand what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Your array contains " id", but not "id" (note the space).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `$fields` array you have third value `id`. There is a whitespace in the beggining of the `id` string. So `in_array("id", $fields)` fails. It will works for:

```
in_array(" id", $fields)
```

You should walk over `$fields` array and trim its values. For example with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$fields = array_map(function($field){ return trim($field); }, $fields);
```

or:

```
$fields = array_map(trim, $fields);
```

or [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
array_walk($fields, function(&$field){ $field = trim($field); });
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'groupName' (length=9)
  1 => string 'userName' (length=8)
  2 => string 'id' (length=2)
```

And the test:

```
var_dump(in_array("id", $fields));
```

Result:

```
boolean true
```

Comment: Why use a function in `array_map()`.   `trim()` is a valid callback.

Answer (score 3):

Its because you have spaces in the array elements;

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "groupName"
  [1]=>
  string(9) " userName"
  [2]=>
  string(3) " id"
}
```

Corrected code:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "groupName"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "userName" // Remove space after "
  [2]=>
  string(3) "id" // Remove space after "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a whitespace in your array value " id", thats why it doesnt match against "id"
you should use trim (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) in order to remove whitespaces from end and beginning of the string before you insert/check.